# jQuery adding to JSP page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a piece of jQuery code which I found on the internet and I want to integrate it to my jsp page, I use Spring form tags.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
(function ($) {
    //тут превращаем select в input    
    var id = "test",
        $id = $('#' + id),
        choices = $id.find('option').map(function (n, e) {
            var $e = $(e);
            return {
                id: $e.val(),
                text: $e.text()
            };
        }),
        width = $id.width(),
        realClass = $id.get(0).className,
        realId = $id.get(0).id,


        $input = $('<input>',{width: width});
    $id.after($input);
    $id.hide();
    $id.find('option').remove();
    //превратили

    $input.select2({
        query: function (query) {
            var data = {}, i;
            data.results = [];

            // подтставим то что искали

            if (query.term !== "") {
                data.results.push({
                    id: query.term,
                    text: query.term
                });
            }

            // добавим остальное

            for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
                if (choices[i].text.match(query.term) || choices[i].id.match(query.term)) data.results.push(choices[i]);
            }

            query.callback(data);
        }
    }).on('change',function()
          {   
              var value=$input.val();
              $id.empty();
              $id.append($('<option>').val(value))
              $id.val(value);             
          }
         );
})(jQuery);
```

CSS file for jQuery - I name it test.css and apply it to my jsp page:

```
#test {
    width: 300px;
}
```

My jsp page

```
 <html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<title>Страница выборки</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/cssFiles/jquery-ui.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/cssFiles/test.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jsFiles/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jsFiles/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jsFiles/jquery-ui-i18n.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/jsFiles/selecter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function()
         {

         $("#parctdate, #chldAdmitDate, #chldSchlDate, #name, #type, #daySchdl, #workSchdl, #rotation, #numbch, #chUnder3, #chUpper3, #chGoSchool, #chAdmitted").mouseenter(function() {        
             $(this).css("background-color", "gainsboro");   
         });

         $("#parctdate, #chldAdmitDate, #chldSchlDate, #name, #type, #daySchdl, #workSchdl, #rotation, #numbch, #chUnder3, #chUpper3, #chGoSchool, #chAdmitted").mouseleave(function() {        
             $(this).css("background-color", "white");   
         });

         var enabledDays = ["6-1-2013", "7-1-2013", "8-1-2013", "9-1-2013", "10-1-2013", "11-1-2013"];
         function nationalDays(date) {
                var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();            
                for (i = 0; i < enabledDays.length; i++) {
                    if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,enabledDays) != -1 || new Date() > date) {           
                        return [true];
                    }
                }
                return [false];
            }

         $(function(){
               $.datepicker.setDefaults($.extend($.datepicker.regional["ru"]));
               $("#datepicker1, #datepicker2, #datepicker3").datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                                                                         duration: "normal",
                                                                         numberOfMonths: [ 1, 2 ],
                                                                         constrainInput: true,
                                                                         beforeShowDay: nationalDays});   
             });         


     });

</script>

</head>

<body>

<spring:message code="label.input.button" var="labelbutton"/>

<h3 align="center"><spring:message code="label.input.topLabel"/></h3>


<form:form  id="myform" cssClass="testClass" modelAttribute="fboAttribute" method="post" action="add" >
<table align="center">  


<tr id="name">
<td><form:label path="institution.nameOfInstitution"><spring:message code="label.input.nameOfInstitution"/></form:label>
<form:select id="test"  path="institution.nameOfInstitution"> 
<form:option  value=""><spring:message code="label.select.msg" />-</form:option>
<form:options items="${listOfInstitutionsNames}"/>
</form:select> 

<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="${labelbutton}"/></td>

</table> 
</form:form>
```

I would like to integrate my jQuery scripts with my jsp and Spring form tags.

I'm sorry I'm new in jQuery.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, by integrate you mean what ?

Comment: Hello sir. I want to integrate jQuery+CSS to my JSP(last my question tab exactly is <form:select  id="test" path="institution.nameOfInstitution">) But I have confused because I did not work with jQuery before. So insted <form:select  id="test" path="institution.nameOfInstitution"></form:select> and all what between select tag I want to use jQuery.   code And as you can see I have <form:options items="${listOfInstitutionsNames}"/> this is my attributes ${listOfInstitutionsNames} fetching and I want put them in jQuery code insted used in jQuery attributes -var test- example.

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library. You shouldn't add HTML code with jQuery. I don't know what you mean by integrate... but you can add the script to the page like this: `<script src="path_to_jquery"></script>`

Comment: Yes sir... I mean instead of my <form:select> use this jQuery code. And  make my attributes appears in jQuery code. My attributes are this ${listOfInstitutionsNames}. Where to add them in jQuery code. and I need iterate over this ${listOfInstitutionsNames} attributes.

Comment: @java_user : do you know how to add jQuery to a a usual HTML page ? If  so, there's not much difference between doing that in JSP and HTML. In fact, jQuery is just like any JS (javascript), you can use it in whichever tag in your HTML (be it Spring or not).

Comment: So you want litteraly to take away the spring form tag ?

Comment: @Gloserio yes sir I want take away the spring form tag

Comment: Ok. But why take it, from what I see it, the difference between what you called "_html for jQuery example_" and Spring form tag is a mere class attribute, I am mistaken in that ?

Comment: But you see, the problem is that it's not work because Spring form has different structure. Like as example it has cssClass not just class like in html example. when I try to add it it doesn't show me anything but when I try to execute it here http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/x4XQp/ it works.

Comment: you tried spring tags in jsfiddle ?

Comment: yes. I use put <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>  to use Spring tags in my jsp

Answer (score 4):

jQuery, like any JavaScript, is added in a `<script>` tag in the `<head>` tag of your JSP page. You either add all the code or just a link to the `.js` file containing your jQuery, like for example :

```
<script src="./libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Having done that, you want now to leverage your jQuery in the HTML tags, you do that as for any HTML page. Namely, in your case, you don't have to take away the spring tags. Let it generate the select/options via your `${listOfInstitutionsNames}`, just add `class="testclass"` to your spring form tag, like this :

```
<form:form  cssClass="testclass" id="myform" modelAttribute="fboAttribute" method="post" action="add" >
```

When rendering the form on a browser, Spring will include in the generated HTML the class attribute with value of testclass.

Hope that helps, best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for answer.... I did like you said it doesn't work. Oh. I don't have class I have cssClass instead in Spring forms. I edit my question above for you

Comment: what is inside `jquery.min.js` file? Is this a standard file we need to put in our web project and use jQuery functions under `<script type="text/javascript">

</script>` ?

Answer (score 1):

For Dynamic Web Project(designed using MVC Model)

Add like this in head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jQuery.js"/></script>
```

I kept my jQuery.js in WebContent folder(with jsp pages).

Comment: what is there inside `jQuery.js` file?  Is this a standard file we need to put in our web project and use jQuery functions under `<script type="text/javascript"> </script>` ?

Answer (score 1):

if what you mean is that you want to **bind Java side information to JS var**, you can do as I did:

1. At Java side, use Google's Gson to encode Java object to Json string.
2. At Java side, use org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(String) to make you Json string escaped as JavaScript.
3. At JSP side, do something like this:

> ```
>     <script>
>     var jsonObject = JSON.parse("<%=yourJsonString%>");
>     </script>
> ```