# Mysql ORDER BY length(col), col is not working

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, jsp

```
     Mysql employee table
```

[image: Mysql database table]

Note: Here emp_id is varchar

```
  String query="select * from employee ORDER BY length(emp_id),emp_id";

  if i run only the above query it works fine......
  Query ouput :
```

[image]

While i run the below jsp code this query is not working

```
<html><head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="example" class="display" width="100%" border="1">
            <thead><tr>
                                        <th>EMPLOYEE_ ID</th>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                                        <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
                                        <th>DESIGNATION</th>              
               </tr></thead>            
<tbody>
        <%    
          try
             { 
              String query="select * from employee ORDER BY length(emp_id),emp_id";
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              Connection con = (Connection)   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","");
              Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
              ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
              while(rs.next())
                              {                                   
                               %>
                               <tr> 
                                   <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
                                   <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
                                   <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
                                   <td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
                               </tr>
                               <% } %>
    </tbody></table>
                            <%
                              rs.close(); stmt.close();con.close();
             }
              catch(Exception e)
                               {  e.printStackTrace(); }
                            %>          
            </div>
<script>
     $(document).ready( function () {
 var table = $('#example').DataTable();
     } );
    </script></body></html>
```

output for jsp:

[image]
Note: in my table emp_id is varchar...................................................................................................................................
Please help me....

Comment: Do u think you have a Error in JSP code , or in SQL query?

Comment: No error in mysql query or in my jsp page....

Comment: emp_id why you have varchar?

Comment: because my emp_id columns also contains alphanumeric values

Comment: is it possible some default option of your Datatable() to alter your order of appearance?

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you..@andrew....

Comment: sir Which Datatable() ? r u talking about is that jquery or else ???

Answer (score 1):

May be your jquery takes the default sorting styles...

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSP Standard Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html) and [JSP Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) instead of using `Scriplet` that is more easy to manage and **less error prone**. Use [SQL Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL7.html) that provides JSTL SQL tags for accessing databases in JSP.

---

If the query is giving correct result in database then there is something wrong in the UI part. Try again with below sample tutorial using [JSTL SQL sql:query Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_sql_query_tag.htm).

Sample code:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>JSTL sql:query Tag</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/TEST" user="root" password="pass123" />

        <sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
            SELECT * from Employees;
        </sql:query>

        <table border="1" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Emp ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${row.id}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${row.first}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${row.last}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${row.age}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now try to access above JSP, which should display the following result:

[image]

Comment: Braj I tried your code...but still i am getting the same...sorting order

Comment: Have you tried with the sample code that I shared you with the basic `table` structure instead of using `jQuery`? It's the issue related to `jQuery`

Comment: how to add jquery file...? is it same as by using <link> tag

Comment: Read [jQuery adding to JSP page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378829/jquery-adding-to-jsp-page)