# Hide elements using jquery on a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I would like to hide the content of my page on a certain condition  how can i do this by using jquery.

> Example

```
if(type=="member")
{
\\hide some elements..
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

The value of type is being fetched by session.getAttribute() from a servlet.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the similar problem to my project on which i had to check if the User is Admin or just a simple User. What i had done is something like this: 
In my jsp page i was retrieving the session (just as you are doing)
 `User user = (User) session.getAttribute("loginDone");` In my case i had named `loginDone` my session Attribute.
 Then in the spot i would like to check what type is the User, i did a piece of scriptlet:

```
<% if (user!= null && user.isAdmin()) { %>
   // the code for the Admin User.
<% } %>

<% if (user != null && !user.isAdmin()) { <%>
   // the code for the simple User.
<% } %>
```

Comment: In my case I just want to remove a few tabs.

Comment: You can use this method as well! If the first condition is true show what you want, if not show something else. All your elements will be there but the were shown depending the condition check.

Comment: If my answer helpd you you can give it an up vote and accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(type=="member"){
  $(yourDom).hide();
}
```

Comment: Can this be used inside a jsp tag??

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with jsp. Just know that, These are javascript codes, Which can be put in <script></script> tag In html file.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (type === "member") {
  $('#target1').hide(); //or
  $('#target1).css('display', 'none'); 
}
```

.hide() is similar to CSS property display:none 
{Also, I just saw xiaocui included that in his example.}

in the second example you can use 'hidden' as the value if you don't want your layout to be affected.

If you're confused about how to add jquery to a jsp page, theres a discussion on that here [jQuery adding to JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378829/jquery-adding-to-jsp-page)